# WebStorm - Indent JSX elements inside curly braces

Tags: webstorm, jsx

I am trying to configure WebStorm 2018.2.5 to achieve this:

```
{ showButton && 
  <Button />
}
```

But WebStorm auto-indents to this:

```
{ showButton && 
<Button />
}
```

I tried to configure HTML and JavaScript rules of the IDE, but failed to achieve the desired result.

The style I am trying to configure is suggested by AirBnB, but I am not interested in applying all of its rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible, please follow [WEB-25338](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25338) for updates